# How to configure Glassfish 3.1.2.2 that I can use admin service remote with security enabled and local with security disabled

Tags: glassfish, asadmin

I need a way to use Glassfish 3.1.2.2 admin service (REST call to deploy and configre) from a remote machine and from local machine (command line and applications).

It is clear that for remote access it is necessary to enable secure admin. If we enable secure admin it will break all local access from applications. These application can not be changed to using https to access the admin service. Only thing I can change is that we can use a different port.

I see two possible ways for me:

1. Using a hack. 
    So I can administrate with secure administrate disable. So I can use plan http. For use a possible solution, because this machine used internally in a test environment.
2. Configure Glassfish that we can use admin service remote via secure access https and from a local environment with http.

We prefer solution 1, because it fit better in our environment and we have lesser effort. 
At the moment I see no way or exist a solution (not for production)?

I tried something for solution 2, simular to http-listener-1 http-listener-2. So use two ports 4848 for local unsecure access and as example 4949 for remote secure access.
But I always fail with configuration. So I start with a step by step configuration. First enable admin interface oon two ports and as second step I want to add the secure access to the new port admin-listener. But I got only one of the ports working.
Please can anyone help me with target configuration? Any domain.xml will be welcome.

Thanks florian

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SSH and run asadmin utilities from remote machine.

Comment: Yes one possible solution.

Comment: Yes @Silence one possible solution. But it is not the prefered solution :), because it runs in a build envronment that do all the stuff with asadmin REST interface. Another not so important point are remote os on this machine are Windows and ssh and scripting setup always a pain